# Why do the following two examples give different sorting order?

Tags: bash, sorting, locale, gnu

I have a script that uses base64 encodes a list of filenames and then sorts them. For the most part the problem works exactly as I needed, but I noticed a really strange thing about the sorting.  The following two

```
(for i in 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9; do base64<<<" $i " ; done)|sort|xargs -d '\n' -n 1 bash -c 'echo -n $(base64 -d<<<"$0")" "';echo
```

v.s.

```
(for i in 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9; do base64<<<" $i " ; done)|LC_ALL=C sort|xargs -d '\n' -n 1 bash -c 'echo -n $(base64 -d<<<"$0")" "';echo
```

You'll observe the output of the first is "7  1  8  2  9  3  4  5  6", the second is "1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9".

My default locale is en_CA.UTF-8.

Answer (score 1):

It's a locale issue. Trimming off the extraneous bits:

```
$ echo $LANG
en_US.UTF-8
$ (for i in 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9; do base64<<<" $i " ; done)|sort
IDcgCg==
IDEgCg==
IDggCg==
IDIgCg==
IDkgCg==
IDMgCg==
IDQgCg==
IDUgCg==
IDYgCg==
$ (for i in 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9; do base64<<<" $i " ; done)|LC_ALL=C sort
IDEgCg==
IDIgCg==
IDMgCg==
IDQgCg==
IDUgCg==
IDYgCg==
IDcgCg==
IDggCg==
IDkgCg==
```

(I'm using `en_US`, but `en_CA` is pretty much the same; it just apologizes more)

As you can see, using the non-`C` locale is doing a case-insensitive sort, `IDcgCg==` comes before `IDEgCg==`, while using the `C` locale, it's the opposite. This is why you see the `LC_ALL=C` often added before anything in a script that needs to have consistent results no matter the user's locale.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not having the same problem as you. However, compare

```sh
(for i in 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9; do base64<<<" $i " ; done) | sort
```

to

```sh
(for i in 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9; do base64<<<" $i " ; done) | LC_ALL=C sort
```

Are the upper/lower case entries sorted differently?